# Storing binary data (images) using Windows Azure. images can be small in size

Tags: image, azure, blob

I am looking into using azure blob storage for storing large number of small size images size ranging in 10k to 100k. details below. thanks for your comments!

requirements.
1. Upload/download requires authorization, and tracking per customer.
2. downloads http friendly
3. eventually - number of images can go to million+. storage cost may matter.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651739/storing-binary-data-images-files-etc-using-wpf-windows-azure) thread answered the 1-2. I was reading on the msdn to find out whether block blob has any min size. that is if the file is 10k, it may still consume say min 64k. I did not get conclusive answer. I found [one blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frogs69/archive/2009/12/17/storage-quotas-and-core-allocation-on-windows-azure.aspx) mentioning 64k min size but it is not very obvious. hence, the question!

in other words - I am wondering if you store a image of size say 10k in azure block blob - will it consume 10k storage or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was reading on the msdn to find out whether block blob has any min
>   size. that is if the file is 10k, it may still consume say min 64k. I
>   did not get conclusive answer. I found one blog mentioning 64k min
>   size but it is not very obvious. hence, the question!

I think a minimum 64K blob size for block blobs is incorrect. Yes, there's an overhead and you can read about that overhead here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx (look under Capacity section).

> in other words - I am wondering if you store a image of size say 10k
>   in azure block blob - will it consume 10k storage or more?

So to answer your question, if you store an image of size 10K, the size of the block blob will be slightly more than that (for the overhead) but certainly not 64K.

Comment: thanks for the reply. based on the blog post referred above, block size should not have any min of 64k and should be close to the size of blob as mentioned by Gaurav. if any one else has more data to support this, do add your comment.