# What datatype should I use for saving a file in a SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework, file, azure-sql-database

In this case it will be potentially large PDF files. I will be using Entity Framework to insert and retrieve the files. Before anyone mentions it, I am aware that many believe that I should only save the path to the file in the database. I am not interested in doing it that way in this instance. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although SQL Azure supports these [datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336233.aspx): `binary, varbinary, image`,
Blob storage might be a better (and cheaper) option:

- [Storing binary data (images, files, etc) using WPF + Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651739/storing-binary-data-images-files-etc-using-wpf-windows-azure)

Comment: Great suggestion! I think I will go with the blob storage via Azure. Although, out of curiosity, can the binary/varbinary/image datatypes support large files (100mb+)?

Comment: They can, but I'd use blob storage for large files. Small files in DB are not a problem, but very large ones will cost you much more than blob storage.